# How do I reassign a task in cDevworkFlow?

Tags: c#

I have a five tasks initially it was assigned to me 
example:
task 1
task 2
task 3
task 4 etc
 and one my task was assigned to me which is not part of my work  so just i want to reassign back to the correct person
how can i achieve this one?

Any Help Much Appreciation! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cDevWorkflow runtime api provides you many handy methods to transfer tasks from one user to another. Below link might help you:

http://cdevworkflow.innovativeglobal.com/API/api/M_cDevWorkflow_cDevDeAPI_deRuntime_reAssignTask_2_f3570541.aspx

```
        string oTaskId = ""; //get the taskId which you want to assign 
        string oNewUserId = ""; //get the target userid

        bool oFlag = oRuntime.reAssignTask(oTaskId, oNewUserId);
```

Hope This helps..!